# Issue with binary variables in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm struggling with this Pyomo model piece:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.IDX = pyo.Set(initialize=range(5))

model.assignment = pyo.Var(
            model.IDX, within=pyo.Binary
        )

#Rest of code
```

It's just a simplified part of my model.

Do you have any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue?

I've noticed that the issue arises when setting the variable to Binary, but there's no problem with any other variable type, for example, NonNegativeReals.

The issue I get is the following:

ERROR: Rule failed when initializing variable for Var assignment with index
None: TypeError: Cannot create a Set from data that does not support
**contains**.  Expected set-like object supporting
collections.abc.Collection interface, but received 'type'.
ERROR: Constructing component 'assignment' from data=None failed: TypeError:
Cannot create a Set from data that does not support **contains**.
Expected set-like object supporting collections.abc.Collection interface,
but received 'type'.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you have an error somewhere?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me on PyOMO 6.6.2